# Is it possible to make netbeans validate html code inside php files?

Tags: php, netbeans, w3c-validation, netbeans-8.1

I have a template PHP file with lots of html, but NetBeans (Version 8.1 RC2) doesn't provide any validation (no warnings/errors, just highlight), validation works only with real HTML files.

Is it possible to make it parse and validate both PHP and HTML code inside a single file? At least, is there any ways to toggle code parsing except of changing file association/extension?

Comment: its only possible if you make your natebeans to consider html code as php code then it will parse all the code.

Comment: It does hightlight html code, but it doesn't validate it as in simple html files, I need exactly html validation in php file

Comment: @Dmi Did you find the solution

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa unfortunately, not. Just moved to another IDE (PhpStorm) where this feature is available.